# Lost in transfer?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Whats going on here?

- Version: `Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)`
- Fully synced local node
- Start balance: `.353514567807`
- Transfer: `transfer <wallet address> .003514567807`
- This should have left a balance of `.35`

```
Transaction 1/1:
Spending from address index 0
Sending 0.003514567807.  The transaction fee is 0.000013560000
```

- `show_transfers` does indeed show the correct transfer amounts
- But the final `balance` in wallet shows only `.053711185393`:

```
Refresh done, blocks received: 0
Currently selected account: [0] Primary account
Tag: (No tag assigned)
Balance: .053711185393, unlocked balance: 6.053711185393
```

Where did the `.296288814607` go?!

Answer (score 1):

False alarm. Must be part of the mixing algo. For some reason the wallet would not sync with local node. Had to run `wallet-cli` as admin to get it to sync to node. After that, a few new tx's came in that balanced things out correctly.